# Traversing a binary tree and keeping a list

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I have implemented a binary parse tree of the CNF form of the propositional logic statements. To check the validity of the propositional logic, first I split the conjuction, then check if an atom or its negation is present. If one them is present, and the other is not, then the function returns false. Otherwise it returns true

However, I'm having a bit of trouble with this...

```
bool Tree::Valid(Node *n = NULL)
{
    if (n == NULL) n = root;
    if (n->data == AND)
        return Valid(n->Lchild) && Valid(n->Rchild);
    bool normal[26], negated[26];
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; ++i)
        normal[i] = negated[i] = false;
    void checkChild(Node *nChild)
    {
        if (isalpha(nChild->data))
            normal[nChild->data -'a'] = true;
        else if (nChild->data == NOT)
            negated[nChild->Rchild->data - 'a'] = true;
        else
        {
            checkChild(nChild->Lchild);
            checkChild(nChild->Rchild);
        }
    }
    checkChild(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; ++i)
    {
        if (normal[i] != negated[i])
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I realized you can't nest function like this, but I don't know how to get around it.

Thanks for your help!

(edit)
Here's an example of a parse tree that I'm implementing. The letters are the atoms, and the '~' stands for negation... which is basically saying negate the right child (which in CNF is always an atom). The atoms can any letter a-z. There are two binary operators '+', '*' and one unary operator '~'. The atoms can be thought of as boolean variables.

The CNF form is defined as:
A := atom | negation of atom
B := A + B | A
C := C * B | B
[image]

Comment: When you used the debugger, which statement is causing the issue?  What variables are involved?  What are the values in the variables when the breakpoint is hit?

Comment: You seem not have error to track on that code, but just understand what's happening. Is that right ?

Comment: what you're searching is a tree traversal if I understood you correctly, simple and most standard way is to have a recursion (find : in order traversal) and send as a parameter a list so you can do w.e- that's in general but please can you represent CNF as a tree(with mspaint or something) and I'll be able to help you better , since to give you a proper answer I need to understand what the nodes are , also since any statement can be either atomic or not you might look at a different tree structure by using "composite design pattern" but as I said i prefer to actually see what you mean :)

Comment: I'm using Code::Blocks and it's saying: "error: a function definition is not allowed here before '{' token". If I comment out the checkChild function and the function call just below it, it compiles with no errors.

Comment: So, you are not able to place the function `checkChild()` inside the function `Tree::Valid()`. Please, declare `checkChild()` in the `class Tree` and move the code outside.

Comment: @Piquard, if I were to do that then I'd have to pass the two arrays also. I'm dealing with large trees. Will that be the optimum way?

Comment: @numberphile the size of both arrays `normal` and `negated` doesn't seem to depend of the tree complexity (always 26 cells). To check the solution, you can place both outside the `Tree::Valid()` and move the code of `checkChild()` before the `Tree::Valid()` function.

Comment: @Piquard. Yeah, I was initially thinking that, however, we've been taught not to declare global variables too much. I guess this can be an exception then.